# Singleton bean inside prototype bean is null

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I'm trying to autowire a singleton bean inside a prototype bean like so:

```
@Component
@Scope("singleton")
class ComponentX {
}
```

and

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
class ComponentY {
  @Autowired
  private ComponentX x;
}
```

but I'm getting null where I need to use x inside ComponentY.

I understand the problem of having things the other way around, but I can't see why in my case it wouldn't let me.

Any idea how to get over this?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: And how is your spring configured? Typically it's because Spring does't know it has to inject the beans... Please add you configs.

Comment: How are you getting an instance of `ComponentY`.

Comment: thanks @M.Deinum, for pointing me to the problem, I was making the mistake of creating ComponentY through new which was effectively by-passing all autowiring. now I'm creating it through appContext.getBean